# Possible to use aspNetActiveDirectoryProvider and aspsqlProfile Provider combined?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Could anyone please provide me with guidance on whether it's possible to use aspNetActiveDirectoryProvider for Authentication and aspsqlProfile Provider to store user specific details?

I'm not quiet getting  my head around on how do I get userID that's required for aspnet_profile table if I were to switch to Active Direcory.

Also, is it possible to change password from aspnet admin page if active directory is used?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing password is possible with AD provider: see [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.ChangePassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.changepassword.aspx) method.

ASP.NET profile generally associates profile with user name. Typically, user name value will be same as the user identity value used by authentication system. So in active directory case, it would be user's domain qualified login-name (in form of `<domain>/<login>`) - see this link for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewfkf772.aspx

You may also create a custom profile provider if you need more control at database schema side  - sample is already available from microsoft and you can use that as base, check these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163457.aspx

http://www.asp.net/downloads/sandbox/table-profile-provider-samples